# make4ht configuration file format

Tags: make4ht

I need to HTMLize several largeish, complex LaTeX documents. Looking around, I see praise for `make4ht`. But there are several snags, that the documentation states can be sidestepped by a `.mk4` configuration file for the file. Reading the documentation bundled with it in TeXlive I wrote a test configuration file `poly-zero.mk4` for `poly-zero.tex` like the documentation seems to suggest:

```
Make:latexmk
```

(I fully intend to add more to this). But I just get:

```
Output dir:     
Compiler:   latex
Latex options:   -jobname=poly-zero 
tex4ht.sty :    xhtml,
tex4ht  
build_file  poly-zero.mk4
Output format   html5
Using build file    poly-zero.mk4
[string "Make:latexmk_build..."]:2: function arguments expected near <eof>
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/mkutils.lua:417: assertion failed!
```

So the documentation-mandated `Make:latexmk` is dead wrong.

Any *reliable* (hopefully also complete) source on how to configure make4ht? I'm completely ignorant of lua, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use valid Lua code in the build file, so you must add `()` to all commands. The correct form is thus `Make:latexmk()`. The documentation is maybe a bit confusing on this point, because it doesn't list [available commands](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#x1-170005.2) with parentheses. It is preceded by the [section about build files](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#x1-110005) where it is discussed an example is provided.

Comment: Damn diagonal reading... and documentation that talks about several types of configuration files, without telling of differences (in format, ...) or no.  Thanks!

Comment: @vonbrand I can try to make the documentation more clear. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please do document switches (what does `-u` mean?) How to invoke extensions (what is  `tidy`? How do I get it to decompose ligatures -- here they just diissapear? The list is long. The examples given have *no* explanation of what they do (it seems they are silly uses of the machinery, not anything remotely realistic). Get rid of all the talk about `htlatex` problems (or move that to an appendix), I want to use `make4ht` precisely because I don't want to meddle with those. Give some configurations for realistic tasks (want HTML + MathML, UTF-8, images in e.g. SVG, in directory so-and-so).

Comment: How do I generate HTML and PDF, reusing as much as possible in terms of intermediate files? (Running LaTeX six times, BibTeX twice, ... isn't much fun for a 400+ page document). How do I split the document into e.g chapters/sections? Can I generate subdirectories for chapters, with files for sections?

Comment: Just cloned the repository from github. The `README.md` file is a huge step in the right direction, the documentation shipped with TeXlive seems outdated.

Comment: @vonbrand thanks for the suggestions, I will try to incorporate them.  The up-to date documentation is on [my website](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html) - it is generated automatically on every commit. The version shipped in TeX Live is bit older, especially if you use TL 2019.